# Firebase Filtering using Radio buttons

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to filter posts from Firebase in other users profiles using RadioButtons like this:
[image]

So what I'm trying to do is check whether the user has a post with the selected meal and if he does, it should appear after clicking on the Filter button.

[image]

This is what I have tried to do to check for one option:

```
 final RadioButton b = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.breakfast);
                bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.btnFilter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        if(b.isChecked())
                        {
                            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");
                            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                                        if(post.getPublisher().equals(profileid) & snapshot.child("Meal").getValue().toString().equals(b.getText().toString()))
                                        {
                                            if (snapshot.child("ingrediant").getValue() != null){
                                                ArrayList<String> mList  = new ArrayList();
                                                for (DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.child("ingrediant").getChildren()){
                                                    mList.add(ds.getKey()+":"+ds.getValue());
                                                }
                                                post.setIngrediantsList(mList);

                                            }
                                            post.setVideo((Boolean) snapshot.child("isVideo").getValue());
                                            postList.add(post);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Collections.reverse(postList);
                                    myFotosAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                }
                            });
```

but it is not working it still showing all posts, not the filtered ones. How can I fix this?
I have checked similar issues here but they didn't work for me.

Comment: So you need the result of a combined query? If yes, would that be?

Comment: yes, I want a query for a user that has a certain Meal type.

Comment: What would that Query be? You can say also in SQL terms.

Comment: well, that's what I couldn't figure out. is it even doable? I know how to access a certain user from firebase but my problem is how to check whether other data exists for that exact user. hope you got my point. please see the Firebase structure in the image above

Comment: What do you mean by "check whether other data exists"?